# Time series normalization, how to handle zeros

Tags: time-series, normalization, data-mining, churn

I'm working on a player churn prediction model for a game. I have number of rounds played time series for 60 days. Before I feed the time series to classification algorithms, I need to normalize the time series.

I was thinking about using min-max normalization by transform x to x/Max(x). Max(x) in the 60 days time series doesn't necessarily captures the peak of how many times a player usually play a day.

But the z-normalization by transform x to (x-mean(x))/std(x) will not work since I need to preserve the information of the days with no play is zero. Doing z-normalization maps 0 to different values which makes them uncomparable.

Is there a normalization scheme which requires no information about the maximum of the time series and can map 0 still to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your values into probabilities by dividing each value in the array by the sum of the values in the array (normalization factor "sum to unity").i.e.transform x to  x./sum(x)
That would map 0 values to 0 and requires no information about the maximum value.

Comment: this cannot be answer.Put as comment